# Synchronous animations in jQuery, not using callbacks?

Tags: jquery, animation

I can't use callbacks because I have a scenario like this (pseudo-code):

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $('.expanded-box').animate({
        // shrink it
    });

    $(this).animate({
        // grow it
        $(this).addClass('expanded-box');
    });
});
```

I can't put the expansion animation within the callback for the `expanded-box` growth animation because it may not always happen. But I need the second animation to wait till the previous one is done. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it may not always happen."?  Do you mean that `.expanded-box` may not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.6, you can use [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to obtain a [Promise object](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) that will be resolved when all animations on a given element have completed. In addition, the documentation says:

> Using .promise() on a collection with no active animation returns a
>   resolved Promise.

Therefore, it's well-suited to your use case, and you can write:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.expanded-box').animate({
        // shrink it
    }).promise().done(function() {
        $this.animate({
            // grow it
        }).addClass('expanded-box');
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, didn't even know about `promise()` - thanks! It works on a lot of different methods, too.

Comment: How is this different to putting the second part in the complete callback of the first animation?

Comment: @nnnnnn, if `$(".expanded-box")` doesn't match anything, the `complete` callback will not be called, as it is called once for each matched element. On the other hand, `promise()` returns a resolved `Promise` object if called on an empty jQuery object, therefore making sure the function passed to `done()` is called in all cases (i.e. even on the first click, when no box is expanded yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the second animation's code in a function and then call that function from the callback of the first animation *or* call it if the first animation doesn't happen. Assuming the idea is to shrink some other control that had the "expanded-box" class from a previous click:

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $exp = $(".expanded-box");

    function grow() {
       $this.animate({
           width: "200px", height: "100px"
       }).addClass('expanded-box');
    }

    if ($exp.length > 0) {
       $exp.animate({
           width: "100px", height: "50px"
       }, grow).removeClass("expanded-box");
    } else {
       grow();
    }        
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PXddm/

Comment: Cool. I had thought of this, but was hoping for a more elegant solution. I thought there was some sort of animation queue feature in jQuery.

Comment: There is definitely an animnation queue feature. It used to apply only per element, but "As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string." - but I've never used that feature so I'm not sure exactly how it works.