# jquery animation callbacks not fired if no elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

If the jquery selector matches no elements then the animation callback functions are not fired.

```
$('.MadeUpClassName').animate({width: '100px'}
                             ,{complete: NeverFired
                              ,done: NeverFired
                              ,fail: NeverFired
                              ,always: NeverFired
                             });
```

I guess it kind of makes sense to have some of the callbacks behave this way.
complete for example is supposed to fire once per element - so no elements means no fire.

However I would have expected a callback with a name like "always" to be fired regardless?
Or are they all fired once per element? (The official api docs don't say)

Is there a workaround for this or an alternative callback function that I've missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronous animations in jQuery, not using callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471969/synchronous-animations-in-jquery-not-using-callbacks) The workaround is to use `promise()` to have your callback invoked even if there are no elements to animate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi
that looks like exactly what I need actually.
It also looks like it solves another problem I have where sometimes I only want the callback to be fired once even when there are multiple elements.

Can you make this answer so I can accept it please?

Comment: I would have to repeat most of my answer from the duplicate, and we usually prefer not doing that (that's why I voted to close your question as a duplicate instead).

Comment: imo my question may be more "searchable" - or else I would have found the previous question before asking my own.
Does marking it as a duplicate retain my question for searching?
If so then I agree - And would mark it as such myself if I knew how...

(this may be off topic and better discussed elsewhere?)

Comment: Duplicate questions still appear in the search results, yes (that's why we don't like deleting them, [we prefer keeping them around](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)). You're always welcome to discuss matters such as this on [meta].